# How to read specific parts of the text file using Java

Tags: java, file-io

I have a text file that contains

```
"[PartA]
1
2
3
[PartB]
4
5
6
[PartC]
7
8
9"
```

what I have done so far is to read [PartA] only
here's my code:

```
try
    {
        BufferedReader fw = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filename)));

        while(!((content=fw.readLine()).equals("[PartB]")))
        {
            System.out.println(content);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
```

so how can I read only PartB or only PartC?

Comment: You could just `continue` instead of printing, then print when ready.

Comment: Don't forget to put a `null` check on `fw.readLine()` to check for EOF.

Comment: @Braj if(fw.readLine==null) break; is that it? sorry I'm still having a hard time comprehending codes (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could say

```
boolean partB = false;
content = fw.readLine();
while(content != null) {
    if(content.equals("[PartA]")) {
        partB = false;
    } else if (content.equals("[PartB]")) {
        partB = true;
    } else if (content.equals("[PartC]")) {
        partB = false;
    }
    if (partB) {
        System.out.println(content);
    }
    content = fw.readLine();
}
```

and follow that same logic for PartC

Comment: while(content=fw.readLine())? wouldn't a while loop need a boolean statement inside? :D

Comment: the boolean is whether or not content is null. If you wanted, you could read the first line outside of the while loop and use while(content!=null) as your conditional and then read from fw at the end of the while loop each time.

Comment: it has an error it says:

"incompatible types: String cannot be converted to boolean"

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit rusty on java, for a quick solution you can use my edited comment.

Comment: No problem, keep in mind there may be (scratch that, definitely is) a more elegant solution, but this will get you through. Good luck for the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
try
    {
        BufferedReader fw = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filename)));
     while(!fw.readLine()).equals("[PartB]"){} //search for PartB
     while(!(content=fw.readLine())).equals("[PartC]")){   //read till PartC
        System.out.println(content);
     }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
```