# How to get specific lines from the file ( between two sections)?

Tags: java

I'm trying to read specific lines in-between two sections using Java 8.

I need to get the information in between `~CURVE INFORMATION` and `~PARAMETER INFORMATION`

I was able to get it using by checking `startsWith()` or `equals` and start storing the lines in some stringbuilder or collection. But is there any method available to get some specific lines in-between some sections.

I was looking at below questions for reference.

[How to read specific parts of a .txt file in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28544691/how-to-read-specific-parts-of-a-txt-file-in-java)

[How to read specific parts of the text file using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664025/how-to-read-specific-parts-of-the-text-file-using-java)

**Sample data from file:**

```
~WELL INFORMATION
#MNEM.UNIT      DATA TYPE    INFORMATION
#----------   ------------   ------------------------------
 STRT.FT        5560.0000:   START DEPTH
 STOP.FT       16769.5000:   STOP DEPTH
 STEP.FT           0.5000:   STEP LENGTH
 NULL.          -999.2500:   NULL VALUE
 COMP.              SHELL:   COMPANY
~CURVE INFORMATION
#MNEM.UNIT       API CODE    CURVE DESCRIPTION
#----------   ------------   ------------------------------
 DEPT.F                  :   
 SEWP.OHMM   99 000 00 00:   
 SEMP.OHMM   99 120 00 00:   
 SEDP.OHMM   99 120 00 00:   
 SESP.OHMM   99 220 01 00:   
 SGRC.GAPI   99 310 01 00:   
 SROP.FT/HR  99 000 00 00:   
 SBDC.G/C3   45 350 01 00:   
 SCOR.G/C3   99 365 01 00:   
 SPSF.DEC    99 890 03 00:   
~PARAMETER INFORMATION
#MNEM.UNIT          VALUE    DESCRIPTION
#----------   ------------   ------------------------------
 RMF .OHMM              -:   RMF
 MFST.F                 -:   RMF MEAS. TEMP.
 RMC .OHMM              -:   RMC
 MCST.F                 -:   RMC MEAS. TEMP.
 MFSS.                  -:   SOURCE RMF.
 MCSS.                  -:   SOURCE RMC.
 WITN.             MILLER:   WITNESSED BY
~OTHER INFORMATION
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Java9 you can do it elegantly with streams

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(args[0]))) {

        System.out.println(stream.dropWhile(string -> !"~CURVE INFORMATION".equals(string)).takeWhile( string -> !"~PARAMETER INFORMATION".equals(string)).skip(1).collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What makes it pleasing is the declarative nature of streams, your literally writing code that says drop elements until start mark then take elements until end mark and join them using "\n"! Java9 added takeWhile and dropWhile, I'm sure you can implement them or get their implementation from a library for java 8. Of course this is just another way to achieve the original goal.